# React - show first item in map based on condition

Tags: reactjs

I have [StackBlitz Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rrefkp)

Simple question is it possible to show the first item in a map based on a conditional.

So in my example how could I just output the first item '1' if 'first' is true

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

  const first = true

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map(item => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. If `first` is true it will only show the first element else it will show all.

```
const App = () => {
  const list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

  const first = false;

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {first ? (
          <li>{list[0]}</li>
        ) : (
          list.map((item, index) => {
            return <li>{item}</li>;
          })
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is the closes but I wanted to show the first item, this hides it - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vatwjg

Comment: @lomine updated the answer. Hope this is how you intended it to work.

Answer (score 2):

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-su1psh)

```
{list.map((item, i) => {
          if (i === 0 && item) return <li>{item}</li>;
        })}
```

Comment: This just output the first item if 'first' is true or false, I need the first item based on a condition

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
    {
        list.map((item,index) => (
            (index === 0 && first) ? <li>{item}</li> : null
        ))
    }
</ul>
```

Try the above code.

Comment: this doesn't show the items which are not indexed 0

Comment: which is not the answer to the problem, that is why I pointed that out?

Comment: This outputs all the item if first id true or false

Answer (score 1):

```
{list.map((item, index) => (
          <li>{first ? (index === 0 ? item : null) : item}</li>
 ))}
```